# Какой выбрать способ обмена данными между процессами, в разных сессиях одной винды?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-8

Речь идет о локальных сессиях под разными пользователями.
Одна программа должна контролировать другие программы в других локальных сессиях под управлением Windows 8.1

Какой самый простой и удобный способ?

Comment: Named pipes? Msmq?

Comment: Да хоть локальный сервер запустить

Comment: [How to: Use Named Pipes for Network Interprocess Communication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication). Пайпы хороши своей производительностью.